# Convert vector values in Pandas rows into new rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, rows, calculated-columns

I have a Pandas Data frame that let say col3 has a list, I need to convert each item of the list into a new row as  follow:

I think I need to transpose on col1 and col2 but not sure.

```
# the data frame that I have:  
pd.DataFrame({"col1" : [1,2,3],
               "col2" : ['x','y','z'],
               "col3" : [['a', 'b'],['c','d','e'],['f']] })


# the output I'm expecting:
pd.DataFrame({'Sample':[1,1,2,2,2,3],
          "col2" : ['x','x', 'y','y', 'y', 'z'],
          'targets':['a', 'b','c','d','e','f']})
```

Comment: `df.explode('col3').rename(columns={'col1': 'Sample', 'col3': 'targets'})`

Comment: `explode` is certainly trendy now..

Comment: Use `pandas` and `explode` is my default answer to all questions!

Comment: explode was a great suggestion! it resolved the issue! THANK YOU SO MUCH everyone for your helpful comments